# Get each quarter data based on month in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My table :

```
   Year  Month   Value1    Value2
   2020   1       100       100
   2020   2       100       100
   2020   3       100       100
   2020   4       100       100
   2020   5       100       100
   2020   6       100       100
   2020   7       100       100
   2020   8       100       100
   2020   9       100       100
   2020   10      100       100
   2020   11      100       100
   2020   12      100       100
```

How my output should look :

```
   Year  Quarter   Value1    Value2
   2020   Q1        300       300
   2020   Q2        300       300
   2020   Q3        300       300
   2020   Q4        300       300
```

what I tried :

```
select year,sum(value1),sum(value2),sum(value3) 
  from table 
 where month=1 or month=2 or month=3 
 group by year;
```

But I'm getting only frst quarter...how to write the sql query

Thanks in advance...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation here.  We can first generate the quarter column in a CTE, then aggregate by year and quarter to get the sums.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        Year, Value1, Value2,
        CASE WHEN Month BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 'Q1'
             WHEN Month BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 'Q2'
             WHEN Month BETWEEN 7 AND 9 THEN 'Q3'
             ELSE 'Q4' END AS Quarter
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    Year,
    Quarter,
    SUM(Value1) AS Value1,
    SUM(Value2) AS Value2
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    Year,
    Quarter
ORDER BY
    Year,
    Quarter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the quarter by dividing the month by 3 and rounding up:

```sql
SELECT Year,
       'Q' || CEIL( month / 3 ) AS Quarter,
       SUM( Value1 ) AS Value1,
       SUM( Value2 ) AS Value2
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       Year,
       CEIL( month / 3 )
ORDER BY
       Year,
       Quarter;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Year, Month, Value1, Value2 ) AS
SELECT 2020,  1, 100, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2020,  2, 100, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2020,  3, 100, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2020,  4, 100, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2020,  5, 100, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2020,  6, 100, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2020,  7, 100, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2020,  8, 100, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2020,  9, 100, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2020, 10, 100, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2020, 11, 100, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2020, 12, 100, 100 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> YEAR | QUARTER | VALUE1 | VALUE2
> ---: | :------ | -----: | -----:
> 2020 | Q1      |    300 |    300
> 2020 | Q2      |    300 |    300
> 2020 | Q3      |    300 |    300
> 2020 | Q4      |    300 |    300
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=94cbdb742fccf44b88cab79cee39fe59)*